# Create a widget from another as prototype

Tags: c++, qt

I need to create a widget with the same type and text from another. My first try will be create a method that check type for multiple cases and return a pointer to it. Something like this:

```
QWidget* createFromAnother(const QWidget* prototype)
{
    QWidget* wOutput = 0;
    if(prototype->metaObject()->className() == "QTextEdit")
    {
       wOutput = new QTextEdit();
    }else if(prototype->metaObject()->className() == "QLineEdit")
    {
       wOutput = QLineEdit();
    }else if(...){ }
         // -- > The rest of bad-designed code


    QString temp = prototype->property("text");
    wOutput->setProperty("text", temp);

    return wOutput;
}
```

Yes... it isn't a good idea. So, before start it. Is there any other ways to solve it?

My Qt version is 4.6.2.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use [`QMetaObject::newInstance()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.7/qmetaobject.html#id-f707570d-41db-4f76-a184-7b1b0c540c21) for this:

```
QWidget* createFromAnother(const QWidget* prototype)
{
    QWidget* wOutput = qobject_cast<QWidget*>(prototype->metaObject()->newInstance());

    QString temp = prototype->property("text");
    wOutput->setProperty("text", temp);

    return wOutput;
}
```

Comment: Note however that this only works if the class constructor has been declared with Q_INVOKABLE.  None of Qt's built-in widgets do this as far as I can tell, so this method wouldn't work for that unless you create sub-classes of the ones you're interested in.